# WebLogic and Webapp Combo Will Not Display Pictures After Crash

Tags: css, weblogic, war, image

I was running a Java webapp in a WAR, in WebLogic 9.2 on my computer, when my computer crashed.   When I restarted my computer everything was working, but the images were not being displayed in the webapp, nor was the webapp picking up the CSS.  Everything is packed into the WAR and I am not using a webLogic.xml to map anything.

Something like this ( the loss of images and CSS, not the computer crash ) happened last year and I eventually fixed it by going into the weblogic admin, stopping the webapp, uninstalling the webapp, reinstalling and starting it again.

That didn't work this time.

Anyone have any ideas what this is about and how I can resolve it.

My org is working on upgrading to WebLogic 11.2 but there is still about a month away.

Thanks much in advance for any clues.

Comment: were the images cached on your browser and hence missing after your comp crash? do they work from someone else's browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit turned out to be a new ServletFilter I was developing.  The ServeltFilter was checking authentication status before letting people through to the JSPs and Servlets in my site.

While I had put conditionals in the ServletFilter to NOT do any filtering on things like the login page,  I didn't do anything like to to make sure files in my /css, /images, /js  directories were left alone.

When I added similar conditionals for these directories, reinstalled the *.war and restarted the *.war the problem cleared up.

I guess I wasn't seeing the problem before my computer and WebLogic crashed because the images and CSS were cached somehow........until the crash.